# Print landscape document on a single page (word 2013)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, documents

I have word document(single page) in landscape mode but its wide and I have to print it on a single page.

I want to print this in landscape mode and the contents should print on a single page.

right now when I print it prints only 75% of the document how do you print the whole document on a single page?

I am using word 2013

Comment: Some printer drivers have a "fit to page" option.  Explore the various options when you go to print.  Otherwise, there are work-arounds, like print to another format, such as PDF, and then resize, as Máté Juhász suggests.  Microsoft has the XPS format that you can save to, or "print as" (it's been awhile), but something like Irfanview may be able to read that and resize it.  There's third party software, like [ClickBook](www.bluesquirrel.com), that lets you resize, re-orient, and resequence to fit almost anything onto almost any output format.  What's you OS and printer?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no straightforward solution for that in word.

Either you can set the page size to the one you need to print on (that will change layout so probably you'll need to format your document again).

Or print the document with current settings to pdf and from pdf you can resize it to fit your page.